# Manipulating custom combo box drop down in datagridview with special condition in display and updating Database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm having a hard time in DataGridView ComboBox DropDown. Can someone enlighten me on how i bind data in a custom ComboBox with a special condition in a datagridview?

something like, If the database table was read and then in a particular column "Status" was populated with 0 or 1. And then in datagridview combobox drop down it should display **unattended** instead of **0** and currently **attended** instead of **1** and then in running the program when i click **attended** it should be updated in database as 1.

Any advice, recommendation or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub loadDataGrid()
    Try
        Dim TQry As String
        TQry = "Select TQ.Que_No, TS.Step_Remarks, T.Trans_Name, TS.Step_No, O.Office_Name, TQ.Date_Arrive, TQ.Time_Arrive, TQ.STATUS FROM TRANS_QUEUE TQ LEFT JOIN TRANS_STEP TS ON TQ.Trans_Step_ID = TS.Trans_STep_ID LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON TQ.Trans_ID = T.Trans_ID LEFT JOIN OFFICE O ON TQ.Office_ID = O.Office_ID"
        Dim TCmd As New SqlCommand(TQry, MysqlConn)
        TCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim TDa As New SqlDataAdapter(TCmd)
        Dim TDt As New DataTable
        TDa.Fill(TDt)
        Dim TBs As New BindingSource
        TBs.DataSource = TDt

        Dim comboboxColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        Dim Status_Data() As String = New String() {"Attended", "Unattended"}
        comboboxColumn.Items.AddRange(Status_Data)
        comboboxColumn.Name = "Status"
        comboboxColumn.MaxDropDownItems = 2
        comboboxColumn.FlatStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        comboboxColumn.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True


        DataGridView1.DataSource = TBs

        DataGridView1.Columns.Remove("Status")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(7, comboboxColumn)

        Dim CountCols As Integer
        CountCols = DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 2
        For index As Integer = 0 To CountCols
            DataGridView1.Columns(index).ReadOnly = True
        Next
        Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " @Function GetTD()", _
        "Important Note", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, _
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Me.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Screenshots:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsm2A.png)

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orgt9.png)

Comment: You are almost there buddy. Look here do some more work with the link and I'll give you a hand https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JohnG nope. this function will be in the button.

Answer (score 0):

i come up on this kind of sol. I discard the combobox dropdown idea and switch to normal button to make the function works and tweak the query.

in query

```
TQry = "Select TQ.Que_No as Queue, TS.Step_Remarks as Remarks, T.Trans_Name as Transactions, TS.Step_No as Steps, O.Office_Name as Office, TQ.Date_Arrive as Date, TQ.Time_Arrive as Time, case TQ.STATUS when 0 then 'unattended' else 'attended' end as Status FROM TRANS_QUEUE TQ LEFT JOIN TRANS_STEP TS ON TQ.Trans_Step_ID = TS.Trans_STep_ID LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON TQ.Trans_ID = T.Trans_ID LEFT JOIN OFFICE O ON TQ.Office_ID = O.Office_ID"
```

in Start button

```
Private Sub Start_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start_Btn.Click
    Dim RowSelected As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    MsgBox(RowSelected)
    SelectedRow("SELECT * FROM TRANS_QUEUE WHERE Que_No like '%" & RowSelected & "%'") 'kwaon ang Que ID sa selected col
    UpQuery("Update TRANS_QUEUE set Status = 1 WHERE Que_No = " & RowSelected & "") 'I update ang status sa selected col

End Sub

Public Sub SelectedRow(ByVal SQCommand As String)
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=BOSS;user=sa;password=pass2017;database=DB_CFSys"
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Cmpr_EMPLogIn As String = Login.UIDTextBox.Text
    Dim SQCmd As New SqlCommand(SQCommand, MysqlConn)
    Dim SQDr As SqlDataReader
    SQDr = SQCmd.ExecuteReader()
    SQDr.Read()
    If SQDr.HasRows Then
        MsgBox(SQDr.Item("Date_Arrive"))
        MsgBox(SQDr.Item("Time_Arrive").ToString)
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub UpQuery(ByVal SQCommand As String)
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=BOSS;user=sa;password=pass2017;database=DB_CFSys"

    Dim SQLCMD As New SqlCommand(SQCommand, MysqlConn)

    MysqlConn.Open()
    SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Successfully Updated")
    MysqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

In a switch(unattended/attended) button

```
Private Sub Status_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Status_Btn.Click
    If count_click = 1 Then
        count_click = 2
        Me.Status_Btn.Text = "Unattended"
        loadDataGridAttended()

    ElseIf count_click = 2 Then
        count_click = 1
        Me.Status_Btn.Text = "Attended"
        loadDataGrid()
    End If
End Sub
```